# Query does not subtract correctly

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have these two tables:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TAB_A;
MYDATE        P4         D1      D2      P5      P6
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
30-OCT-12    949,324  4,437,654  10,203,116  25,303,632  13,900,078


SQL> SELECT * FROM TAB_B;
MYDATE        P4         D1      D2      P5      P6
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
30-OCT-12    937,796  4,388,477  10,091,811  25,028,402  13,755,882
```

I need to subtract their respective columns and store the results into a third table like so:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TAB_C (MYDATE, P4) SELECT SYSDATE,A.P4-B.P4 FROM  TAB_A A,TAB_B B WHERE A.MYDATE=B.MYDATE;

SQL> SELECT * FROM TAB_C;
MYDATE        P4         D1      D2      P5      P6
--------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
30-OCT-12     926,268
```

The result is wrong. Basic math: `949324-937796=11528`. Numeric values are stored as number datatypes. What am I missing here?

Comment: Seems as if this is implied, but do TAB_A and TAB_B have exactly one row (the one shown)?

Comment: Yes. Both tables have one and only one row. It's a batch job. Tables get truncated every time.

Comment: It does seem strange.  One thing to note is that 949324-926268=2*11528.  In other words, the computed tab_c.p4 = tab_b.p4 - 11528.  And tab_c.p4 = tab_a.p4 - 2*11528.

Comment: Is there a trigger on `TAB_C`? Could it be doing something to change the inserted value?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SYSDATE ,A.P4, B.P4, A.P4-B.P4 
FROM  TAB_A A,TAB_B B 
WHERE A.MYDATE=B.MYDATE
```

make sure the p4 values are what you expect...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_C (MYDATE, P4)
VALUES (SYSDATE, SELECT (A.P4-B.P4) FROM  TAB_A A, TAB_B B WHERE A.MYDATE=B.MYDATE)
```